# How to get images from a directory and print it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php script which works perfectly fine, but am told to use JQuery or JavaScript to do that particular task that the php script does..

here's the code

```
<?
 $files = glob("Logo/*.*");
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
     $image = $files[$i];
     echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" width="100px" 
     height="100px" class="displayed"/>';
    }
?>
```

As said above this php code works fine and i wish to have a JQuery code or JavaScript code that can do that task.

Comment: You can't. JavaScript runs on the client, not the server.

Comment: Are you using Node.js on the server side?

Comment: Please describe your environment better. If you are running jQuery/JS client-side, as I suspect, you don't have access to the filesystem (nor the client's nor the server's).

Comment: I want to run a jQuery or JS on the client side to open a folder and display the image in html

Answer (score 0):

You can send ajax request to your php script and print data to page by jquery. Will be this resolution good for you?

Comment: it won't be good as i am actually comverting html to xhtml and that php script does not run

Comment: You can return list of files as json and build DOM at client side - i did'n understand what problem are you mean

Comment: the php code above for example is found in a file named home.php,this works when i run it,but when i change the home.php extension to .html or xhtml it does not work. i know the file extension have to be php.But i want the file to be home.xhtml or home.html and i want a code to work at the client side so that it get the image from the folder logo and display it in the image tag

Comment: at first - you can call file as xhtml and run php code - need just tweak your server. And as i understand - you did'nt agree with ajax request?

Comment: i did it with Ajax and Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer on this site ...  :D
http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/